# mod_rewrite works when accessed internally but not externally

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following mod_rewrite rule in apache config to force all traffic through https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This is working great when I access the server from inside the same network. When I access it externally, the rewrite doesn't take place and it doesn't change to https. I'm using the same url to access it in both cases.

Any idea why this is happening and what can be done about it?

**EDIT:** I can't answer my own question yet because of my low reputation, but I found the issue:

**Solution**

This server needs to be PCI compliant, so it turns out the firewall I'm behind blocks port 80 entirely. That means the request never even makes it far enough to do the re-write when coming from the outside.

That means you have to request https to begin with since I can't forward it. (Maybe I can see if I can have the firewall do this, but that's a separate issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `RewriteCond` to be based on server port:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

### EDIT:

**Nevertheless,** you've determined that the rule isn't the problem.

Turn on your [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) in either your apache config file or your vhost config and see what mod_rewrite is up to.

Also, provide the output of `iptables -L`

Comment: This is actually the rule I had first. Same thing with this one. Works from inside but not outside. It makes it seem like some other setting is interfering.

Comment: @William Thanks for the update. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @William Where is the rule configured?

Comment: @WesleyDavid That second rule seems a bit wacky ;)

Comment: The RewriteLog has the successful rewrite from my internal attempt. There is not even a single entry from the external attempt.

Also, here is the server's iptables -L output:
http://pastebin.com/uF4mSeuh

Comment: @Shane It's configured in http.conf right after the modules are loaded. It's not in any subsection.

Comment: Do you have any `<VirtualHost>` blocks in use anywhere?